# Using OpenSSH to create overlay IPv6 network

Tags: ssh, networking, vpn, openssh, ipv6

If there's a SSH setup like this:

Host A -> Host B <- Host C

Where Host C is behind a NAT/firewall an opens a reverse tunnel to Host B and Host A connects to Host C via Host B (ProxyCommand). Everything is IPv4 only.

Is there a simple way to establish IP(v6) connectivity between Host A and Host C without requiring extensive root access and intrusive methods on any of those hosts?

EDIT: Basically something similar

```
hostC$ ssh -R 1234:localhost:22 hostB # establis remote hole for host C on host B
hostA$ ssh -o"ProxyCommand=ssh hostB nc localhost 1234" # Connect via HostB to Host C 
hostA$ ping6 <ipv6> # this would validate the connectivity to HostC
```

And the idea would be for the IP(v6) network to be as transient as possible. A service listening on :::1 on HostC should be reachable from HostA.

Comment: Why do you believe everything is IPv4 only?  Could you clarify your question with example (ssh) commands to show how you are opening these connections?

Comment: We cannot guess the layout of your network. What have you tried to do? Also the last sysadmin admin that made an adhoc ipv6 network to explore a setup error of a former workmate forgetting to close ipv6, was fired. Oh, and the adhoc network was made with ipv6 public addresses that belonged to someone else, to boot.

Comment: I've checked the manual `-R` does support IPv6 https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh

Comment: Added some clarifications. Simple port forwarding is not the issue, IP connectivity is. Just thinknig that ipv6 would maybe provide a better mechanism and bigger address space for this than ipv4

Comment: "transient" or "transparent"? You wrote the former but your context seems to suggest the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are confusing SSH port forwarding with VPNs.  These are very different concepts with different capabilities.

SSH Port forwarding lets one server (ip and port) masquerade as another server (ip and port).  From your diagram, this would let Host A think it was talking to Host B (port 1234) when it's actually talking to Host C (port 22) because Host B is forwarding the traffic.  Note Host A never knows Host C exists.

I think what you are actually after is a VPN, where host A can talk to Host C (knowing it is talking to Host C) and all the traffic is sent via Host B.

You can't do this with ssh alone.  Typically all hosts (A, B and C) would need the same VPN software installed (eg OpenVPN).  B would be setup as the VPN server, A and C as clients.

There is one exception. [sshuttle](https://www.unixmen.com/sshuttle-poor-mans-vpn-ssh/) will let an ssh server act like a VPN server, as long as you have sshuttle on the client, the server doesn't need to know.  However it may not work in the configuration you're after.  It probably won't let hosts A and C talk to each other.

Comment: Thanks!I’m not mixing port forwarding with vpn, just making it very clear what I want the tunneling medium to be ;) The overview of sshutle https://sshuttle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html reads exactly like my thoughts. The goal is to not run additional server like openvpn on host C and to have the vpn tied to the ssh session